# How to correctly link C++ app with subversion on MacOS?

Tags: svn, macos

What is the best way to link my C++ app with subversion on MacOS? On windows i can use "dev" package with headers and libraries, for linux i can use libsvn-dev. But what is the easiest way for MaxOS? I can't find any headers or libraries for subversion with fresh snow leopard + xcode install. Example svn client wants something like this to compile:

```
cc minimal_client.c -o minimal_client \
-I/usr/local/include/subversion-1 -I/usr/local/apache2/include \
-L/usr/local/apache2/lib -L/usr/local/lib \
-lsvn_client-1 -lapr-0 -laprutil-0
```

This will work on linux but will not work on MacOS since there is no "/usr/local/include/subversion" etc. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [subversion package](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/Portfile) with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) will give you library and include files in `/opt/local/`

Comment: Thanks! Is it any difference if i use Fink or MacPorts?

Comment: I would go with MacPorts, it has more active development. And Fink's package of subversion is still at 1.4.6...